# Is there a way to log in network tab?

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-chrome, firefox

I'm using JavaScript tools that makes XHR requests in background, so It's not possible to see any info about the calls on the network tab (neither Chrome nor in Firefox).

I would like to know if It could be possible to register manually an ajax request as we can do `log()`, `error()`, etc. **without doing the request twice, just log that action to can access its info from the dev tools**. Because It would be great to make an issue or pull request to add that functionality.

---

It's not important, but I'm working with Ionic to make apps with Cordova, there is [a plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) which makes AJAX request in a background thread. In [this issue](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http/issues/167) they says that It's not possible to get information about request in network tab. Even with this clarification, the question is about logging on network tab, not about my tools, or default behaviour of dev tools. Even all request appears in network tab, I want to know if It's possible to make on my own manually.

Comment: The network tab should show all network requests

Comment: When you say "in background" what do you mean?

Comment: If you make an XHR/Ajax call, the network tab will show it. It shows everything in and out. If it doesn't, you're not making a call.